# How do I use the if __name__=='__main__' function when the code I want to store is at the end

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my code I am trying to use the `if __name__=='__main__'` function however the variables I want to share are after the code I don't want to run.
For example:

ProgramA.py

```
if __name__=='__main__':
   fname = input('what is your first name')
   sname = input('What is your second name')
```

ProgramB.py

```
import ProgramA
print(fname)
print(sname)
```

Now I don't want this code to run when importing the variables `fname` and `sname` to use in my other program, I only want the variables not the code that accompanies them. However when I use the `if __name__='__main__'` function and try and save the variables afterwards ProgramB says that the variables aren't defined. Sorry if this is already answered in another question, but so far I have found no solution.

Comment: You need ``from ProgramA import fname, sname``.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Where exactly are you using `if __name__ == '__main__'`?

Comment: Edited original question

Comment: If you run `ProgramB.py`, then `__name__` will never be `__main__`

Answer (score 2):

When you `import ProgramA` you can then reference `fname` and `sname` which are still the values from ProgramA given from:

```
fname = input('what is your first name')
sname = input('What is your second name')
```

By referencing `ProgramA.fname` and `ProgramA.sname` like this:

```
import ProgramA
print(ProgramA.fname)
print(ProgramA.sname)
```

Alternatively you could import it like this:

```
from ProgramA import *
print(fname)
print(sname)
```

You shouldn't use `if __name__ == "__main__"` in ProgramA. `__name__` is only equal to `"__main__"` if Python is loading this source code file as the main program, and as it is being imported from ProgramB `__name__` does not equal `"__main__"` and therefore the variables `fname` and `sname` are never declared, which is why you get this error. You can use `if __name__ == "__main__"` in ProgramB though.

Comment: TY, but how would I make the names print without running the code asking for the first and second names in ProgramB

Comment: @ABo I'm not sure what you're asking. Obviously you can put `fname = input('what is your first name')` and `sname = input('What is your second name')` in ProgramB and just delete ProgramA.py entirely and get rid of its import in ProgramB, but I thought that wasn't the point of the question.